# How to determine if the given postal code is between (K2T - K4P)

Tags: php

How to determine if the given postal code is between (K2T - K4P). This is my code. Looking to get the right results from get_rate_code();

```
class Helpers 
{

    const ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static function getBetweenLetters($first_letter = "A", $last_letter = "Z") {
        $first_letter_position = strpos(SELF::ALPHABET, $first_letter);
        $last_letter_position  = strpos(SELF::ALPHABET, $last_letter) +1;
        return substr(SELF::ALPHABET, $first_letter_position, ($last_letter_position-$first_letter_position));
    }

    public static function getBetweenNumbers($first_number = 0, 
                                             $last_number = 9, 
                                             $target_number = 0) 
    {
        $string = "";
        for($x = $first_number; $x < $last_number+1; $x++) {
            if($x == $target_number)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class DeliverySBR 
{
    // Properties
    public $prov;
    public $destination;
    public $rate_code;
    
    function __construct($destination = "") {
        $this->destination = $destination;
    }

    function set_destination($destination) {
        $this->destination = $destination;
    }

    function get_destination() {
        return $this->destination;
    }

    function get_rate_code() {
        switch ( substr($this->destination, 0, 1) ) {
            case "K": 
                if( substr($this->destination, 1, 1) == 0 &&  is_int(strpos(Helpers::getBetweenLetters("A", "M"), substr($this->destination,2,1) )) )
                    return "D2 (K0A- K0M)"; // K0A- K0M
                else if( Helpers::getBetweenNumbers(1,2,substr($this->destination, 1, 1) ) && is_int(strpos(Helpers::getBetweenLetters("A", "R"), substr($this->destination,2,1) ) ) )
                    return "B2 (K1A- K2R)"; // K1A- K2R;
                else if (substr($this->destination,1,2) == "2S")
                    return "D2 (K2S)"; // K2S
                else if (Helpers::getBetweenNumbers(2,4,substr($this->destination, 1, 1) ) && is_int(strpos(Helpers::getBetweenLetters("P", "T"), substr($this->destination,2,1) )  ) )
                    return "B2 (K2T - K4P)"; // K2T - K4P
                else if (Helpers::getBetweenNumbers(4,7,substr($this->destination, 1, 1) ) && is_int(strpos(Helpers::getBetweenLetters("H", "R"), substr($this->destination,2,1) )  ) )
                    return "D2 (K4R - K7H)"; // K4R - K7H
                //else if()
                //    return ""; // K7K- K7P
            break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    $delivery1 = new DeliverySBR("KOMB73");
    d($delivery1->get_rate_code(), $delivery1->get_destination()); // Works good result: "D2 (K0A- K0M)"

    $delivery2 = new DeliverySBR("K2S173");
    d($delivery2->get_rate_code(), $delivery2->get_destination()); // Works good result: D2 (K2S)

    $delivery3 = new DeliverySBR("K2TL47");
    d($delivery3->get_rate_code(), $delivery3->get_destination()); // Works good result: B2 (K2T - K4P)


    $delivery4 = new DeliverySBR("K4R1L3");
    d($delivery4->get_rate_code(), $delivery4->get_destination()); // BAD gets B2 (K2T - K4P) instead of D2 (K4R - K7H)
    
    $delivery5 = new DeliverySBR("K2Z1L3");
    d($delivery5->get_rate_code(), $delivery5->get_destination()); // BAD this returns null. expecting to return B2 (K2T - K4P)
}
```

its giving me wrong results:

```
d($delivery4->get_rate_code(), $delivery4->get_destination()); // BAD gets B2 (K2T - K4P) instead of D2 (K4R - K7H)
```

and

```
d($delivery5->get_rate_code(), $delivery5->get_destination()); // BAD this returns null. expecting to return B2 (K2T - K4P)
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What are the rules behind "between K2T and K4P"?

Comment: Is `K3Z` in that range?  What are the rules?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're overengineering this, since these codes are directly comparable. The following should suffice:

```php
function get_rate_code(string $postalCode): string
{
    $rateCodeRanges = [
        'D2 (K0A- K0M)' => ['start' => 'K0A', 'end' => 'K0M'],
        'B2 (K1A- K2R)' => ['start' => 'K1A', 'end' => 'K2R'],
        'D2 (K2S)' => ['start' => 'K2S', 'end' => 'K2S'],
        'B2 (K2T - K4P)' => ['start' => 'K2T', 'end' => 'K4P'],
        'D2 (K4R - K7H)' => ['start' => 'K4R', 'end' => 'K7H'],
    ];
    foreach ($rateCodeRanges as $rateCode => $rateCodeRange) {
        if ($postalCode >= $rateCodeRange['start'] && $postalCode <= $rateCodeRange['end']) {
            return $rateCode;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Calling the following:

```php
var_dump(get_rate_code('K0M'));
var_dump(get_rate_code('K2S'));
var_dump(get_rate_code('K2T'));
var_dump(get_rate_code('K4R'));
var_dump(get_rate_code('K2Z'));
```

will give you:

```
'D2 (K0A- K0M)'
'D2 (K2S)'
'B2 (K2T - K4P)'
'D2 (K4R - K7H)'
'B2 (K2T - K4P)'
```

I've made the function return an empty string on no match to keep it down to a single return type, but you can adapt this to whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Live test available [here](https://3v4l.org/5lBun).

Comment: Regarding return types, `string|false` is a valid return type since PHP 8.0 and `?string` represents "string or null" since PHP 7.1.

Comment: @IMSoP I don't know where my head was stuck. Somewhere in the clouds I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern and duplicate for the other code ranges:

```
if(preg_match('/K(2[T-Z]|3[A-Z]|4[A-P])/', $this->destination)) {
    return "B2 (K2T - K4P)";
}
```

- Match `K` and
- `2` and `T-Z` OR `|`
- `3` and `A-Z` OR `|`
- `4` and `A-P`